# What's the meaning of "This method is not thread safe."

Tags: image, windows-phone-7, resources

What's the meaning of "This method is not thread safe."

The question is coming from: Application.GetResourceStream Method.

It teturns a resource stream for a resource data file that is located at the specified Uri (see WPF Application Resource, Content, and Data Files).
Namespace:  System.Windows

Assembly:  PresentationFramework (in PresentationFramework.dll)

Remarks 
This method is not thread safe.

Here's [a link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.WINDOWS.APPLICATION.GETRESOURCESTREAM%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22SILVERLIGHT%2cVERSION%3dV4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true)

Will there be some potential problem when using it?

Answer (score 0):

Thread-safety means an object can be manipulated from more than one thread without issues. What you're being told is you should not call the method from a thread other than the one that created it.

Obviously this is only an issue if you are creating threads in your application.

Comment: Note that you can still potentially use the object in more than one thread, _if_ you take explicit steps to ensure that no more than one thread will access the object's data at a time. (For instance, by wrapping a synchronization primitive around it.)